# Connection closed with error?

Tags: android, xmpp

Xmpp Connection with android, get exception after login, connection close with error , org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: Parser got END_DOCUMENT event. This could happen e.g. if the server closed the connection without sending a closing stream element,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Please set packet timeout

connection.setPacketReplyTimeout(10000)